# Error array destructuring en Slint Vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

Hola a todos buenas noches, acudo a ustedes para preguntar acerca del error "array destructuring" en VueJS2 usando Eslint, tengo la siguiente funcion en mi method:

```
 onCellChange(columnIndex) {
      for (const item of this.params.data) {
        if (item[0] === columnIndex) {
          this.result.id = item[0]
          this.result.nombre = item[1]
          this.result.tercerDato = item[2]
        }
      }
 }
```

Puedo resolver esto desactivando Slint en estas lineas más sin embargo quisiera saber como puedo resolver esto y si me puedieran explicar el del por que de estos errores para no cometerlos; Dejo el codigo sin ningún error marcado desacticando Slint en mi función.

```
  onCellChange(columnIndex) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const item of this.params.data) {
    if (item[0] === columnIndex) {
      /* eslint-disable prefer-destructuring */
      this.result.id = item[0]
      this.result.nombre = item[1]
      this.result.tercerDato = item[2]
    }
  }
  console.log(this.result)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como indica la [documentación de ESLint para prefer-destructuring](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring), la regla `prefer-destructuring` se puede aplicar a dos propiedades: `array` y `object` y por defecto están activo. Lo que te obliga a utilizar la desestructuración en Objetos y Arrays. (Para saber más sobre la desestructuración puedes visitar la [documentación aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

En tu caso, el error se activa por el acceso a los valores del `array` en estas líneas:

```
if (item[0] === columnIndex) {
    this.result.id = item[0]
    this.result.nombre = item[1]
    this.result.tercerDato = item[2]
}
```

Según la documentación, acceder a los valores utilizando `item[0]`, `item[1]`, `item[n]`, etc... es incorrecto si tienes la regla activa (recuerda que `prefer-destructuring` básicamente te obliga a preferir usar desestructuración para acceder a los valores). Una forma sería deshabilitando esta regla como lo hiciste, pero si quisieras usarla tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
onCellChange(columnIndex) {
    for (const item of this.params.data) {
        const [id, nombre, tercerDato] = item; // aplicamos la desestructuración de array
        if (id === columnIndex) {
            this.result.id = id
            this.result.nombre = nombre
            this.result.tercerDato = tercerDato
        }
    }
}
```